# Youtube Data API CommentThreads.list: Original text and display text in comment thread showing "\u0445\u0430\u0432\u044b"

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I found some source code on Google Developers website that helps me retrieve YouTube comments through the `CommentThreads.list` YouTube Data API endpoint, but when I execute the program you can see within the JSON response that the properties `dispayText` and `originalText` contain the following text:

`\u0445\u0430\u0432\u044b`.

(it can be various).

Please give me a hint of what I did wrong this is the code.

```
import os
import json
import googleapiclient.discovery

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY =*****

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.commentThreads().list(
        part="snippet,replies",
        videoId="8X2Eg92x0xE",
        textFormat='plainText'
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(json.dumps(response,indent=2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The API endpoint's response was:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
  "etag": "EXoRH0QLHj489CmlxFtx7SfMdXs",
  "nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pM056MG5DWURxZktNbFBvU25OV01ENHNEUS03TlJBTXRtclJxdEJtbHNPaXZUYVBmWDVSZVJpZm1Hb0dlSVdWajc0aGxNV0lVRQ==",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 20,
    "resultsPerPage": 20
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "8HgQH2sV128K2QYibRSRobFwCLw",
      "id": "UgwWhSYuhI4Dyq5xEo14AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "8X2Eg92x0xE",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "xWiR7YCUHFOiUPTXDk9ghd_VYIA",
          "id": "UgwWhSYuhI4Dyq5xEo14AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "8X2Eg92x0xE",
            "textDisplay": "\u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430 \u0432 7 \u0447\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438 \"\u043d\u0435 \u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0435\u0442\". \u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430 \u0432 8 \u0447\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438 \"\u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0435\u0442 \u0432\u0441\u0451 \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e\"",
            "textOriginal": "\u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430 \u0432 7 \u0447\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438 \"\u043d\u0435 \u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0435\u0442\". \u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430 \u0432 8 \u0447\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438 \"\u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0435\u0442 \u0432\u0441\u0451 \u0447\u0442\u043e \u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e\"",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that code.

Those are [JSON Unicode escape-sequences](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7), which encode in plain ASCII text [Unicode code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

The JSON string `"\u0445\u0430\u0432\u044b"` gets decoded to UTF-8 as `"хавы"`:

```bash
$ json -Pl <<< '"\u0445\u0430\u0432\u044b"'
"хавы"

$ jq <<< '"\u0445\u0430\u0432\u044b"'
"хавы"
```

(Above, I used the programs `json` -- which is part my own application [Json-Type](https://www.nongnu.org/json-type/) -- and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).)